# Как сделать стрелку назад, чтоб возвращала прошлую страницу

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

например будет не стрелка ,а кнопка

Кнопка назад

Возвращение идет не на прошлую страницу,а на прошлую вкладку

Comment: <button onclick="">Кнопка назад</button>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp ?

Comment: Нужно более детально описать то что вы хотите сделать, и на чем пишете.  Куда должно возвращаться ?

Comment: Может вам достаточно простого <a href="ссылка на предыдущую страницу">Назад</a>

Comment: У меня есть страница ,я например нажимаю на определенный блок, меня переносит на новую вкладку,мне на новой вкладке например по кнопке назад, надо вернуться на первоначальную страницу

Answer (score 1):

Об этом разговор?

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ответ слишком прост для того что бы быть верным.  Если придти на страницу из "Вне" ваш метод работать не будет.